# How do you make a dynamic link to another workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have numerous workbooks titled in the format "Year Detailed", e.g. "2000 Detailed.xlsx", "2001 Detailed.xlsx", ... "2018 Detailed.xlsx".

I am trying to make a summary sheet in another workbook, Summary.xlsx.

Is there a way to dynamically link to another workbook where part of the workbook name is based on the value of a cell?

For example, column A is a list of years starting A1 = 2001, and column B is a "total" column that looks at the workbook for "2001 Detailed" and does some math magic to return a value.

So this does what I want

```
=SUM('[2001 Detailed.xlsx]Friday Detail'!$K$4,'[2001 Detailed.xlsx]Saturday Detail'!$K$4)
```

But I then have to re-write it for each year to update the referenced file to the next year.

I have tried to make a Defined Name to do it. I have tried to concatenate in the formula but it just opens a Finder window to open the file.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Formula but since you are using Workbooks so every time Excel will prompt you to OPEN them to SUM, so best is VBA (Macro) to accomplish the job.

Comment: @RajeshS ok, I may do that but I haven't played with VBA in a couple years. I was told that Excel Online will remove macros though? So if I do this in a folder that is synced on onedrive, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'[" &$A$1 & " Detailed.xlsx]Friday Detail'!$K$4"),INDIRECT("'[" &$A$1 & " Detailed.xlsx]Saturday Detail'!$K$4"))
```